# Is manage.py collectstatic needed on each edit of static file?

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I was using django- `1.3.1` by now. Want to give a try to latest version i.e `1.8.1`. So, configured a test project. I was unfamiliar how to tackle with static files with [django-1.8.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/), since explored it more.

I created a `/var/www/appmedia/` directory and put my static components  in to it. like `bootstrap, css, js, images, etc`.

**settings.py**.

```
"""
Django settings for myapp project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.1...
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '+3)e5#343!^(cvy8f9c4hpku*h#$z8*sa)(7a#azv1!!z@d--wsq5s5'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp.common'
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myapp.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ["/home/trex/Work/myapp/myapp/templates"],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myapp.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': "myapp",
        'USER':"postgres", 
        'PASSWORD':"postgres", 
        'HOST':"" 
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/trex/Work/myapp/myapp/static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/var/www/appmedia/',
)
```

To collect static I run `python manage.py collectstatic` which created following

**directory structure**:

```
├── myapp
│   ├── common
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   └── static
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── admin
│   │   ├── bootstrap
│   │   ├── css
│   │   ├── images
│   │   ├── js
│   │   └── scripts
│   └── templates
└── manage.py
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

The issue is, I'm unable to edit my static files. Always have to keep it in `/var/www/appmedia` to edit it, run the `collectstatic`, then only my changes to static files  are reflecting. Did I miss something in configuring static files?

Comment: Which server do you use? Are you working on development or production?

Comment: @Wtower - I'm just trying 1.8.1. So, on local machine using `mangae.py  runserver`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is because you are pointing your server to

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/trex/Work/myapp/myapp/static'.
```

When developing and using `runserver`, running `collectstatic` is not needed, nor does `STATIC_ROOT` need to be set. You can simply use the files from your "static" folder that you define at the app level. `STATICFILES_DIRS` is used only when you have static files that you are using from a different location than a "static" directory in your apps.

Check out the documentation on this with attention to the different ways you serve your files: development vs. production

## editing for code addition to urlconf

```
from django.conf import settings 
from django.contrib.staticfiles.views import serve 
if settings.DEBUG: 
    urlpatterns += [ url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve), ]
```

Comment: Thanks, but removing `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATICFILES_DIRS` also not worked. Am I missing anything else?

Comment: Try to use serve for development purposes. This will work only if debug is True. You will need something like this in your urls: from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.views import serve

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
        url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve),
    ]

Comment: Let me try. Thank you

Comment: Thank you. Worked!!, But code addition was not required. Removed `STATIC_ROOT` , `STATICFILES_DIRS` and a line from url.py
`+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)`

Answer (score 1):

For the development server of Django, you can add the following in your settings file:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    'static/',
)
```

This should be good enough and you wouldn't need to run `collectstatic` each time.

For your live server settings remove this line or set it to None and make sure to add `STATIC_ROOT`.

Comment: @Wtower - Thank you for answer. but didn't work. Throws 404 for all static files. Do I need to remove `STATIC_ROOT` from the settings?

Comment: @mevious sorry to tell you but I don't use this in my live settings and I do use `collectstatic`.

Comment: @trex sorry to hear that. This is how I do it in my settings.

Answer (score 1):

I just went through the same issue and after spending hours on it I finally found the easiest break through. Chaos's method didn't work for me so I dug a little deeper and changed static settings to following:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

if DEBUG:
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),'static','static-only')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),'static','media')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),'static'),)
```

After this I had changed my urls.py file which now has the following addition

```
if settings.DEBUG:
   urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root = settings.STATIC_ROOT)
   urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Needless to say, you have to import settings into your urls.py file